# Javascript - Angularjs - leaflet. Translation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

Everywhere I look on the internet/docs about leaflet I always see this type of statement, example :

```
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', { zoomControl:false });
```

What does it mean?

And how Can I integrate it in Angularjs?

P.S. : **html-leaflet tag**

```
<div id="map">
<leaflet class="leafletmap" markers="markers" lf-center="center"
height="300px" width="785px"></leaflet>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`L.mapbox` comes from the custom Leaflet implementation by Mapbox called [Mapbox.js](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.4.0/). angular-leaflet-directive however uses the standard Leaflet library and with the directive options, markers etc. are defined in a different way.

For angular-leaflet-directive to work you don't need an extra map `<div>`, you just put this somewhere:

```
<leaflet id="map" class="leafletmap" defaults="myDefaults" markers="markers" lf-center="center" height="300px" width="785px"></leaflet>
```

To add `zoomControl` to the map you add `defaults="myDefaults"` to the directive, and then specify the Leaflet default options in your controller:

```
angular.extend($scope, {
    defaults: {
      scrollWheelZoom: false
    }
}
```

You can see an example here: https://plnkr.co/edit/rZbuHmAwA7q7WtBAZg4W

You can find more examples in the [angular-leaflet-directive documentation](http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/#!/examples/simple-map).